# Is there any other way, using CSS, to get an element to NOT influence the flow of the page, besides using the positions absolute or fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried Googling this question, as well as searching for it here but I can't seem to find anything relevant (which suggests that it is not possible).

I've also tried playing around with combination of using "relative" positioning with different "display" properties (like inline, inline-block, etc.), but not at all to my surprise I have found that it still affects the flow of the page. That's pretty much what I understood anyway, but then it got me to thinking, "Is there any other way, using CSS, to get an element to NOT influence the flow of the page, besides using the positions absolute or fixed?"

I would also be interested in any way to achieve the same effect using JavaScript/jQuery, if it's even possible.

Comment: why would you want to do that ? Any specific usecase?

Comment: How do you expect the element to be positioned if it doesn't participate in normal flow?

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve? It is possible you are going about it the wrong way, but without describing it, we can't tell.

Comment: @karthikr Well, honestly because I don't want to inject a certain image, that I want to control "relatively", into a "relatively" positioned container, thus allowing me to use absolute as such. It's a nuisance to do that every time I come into this scenario, but if that's what it takes, that's what it takes.

Comment: @Oded I just was hoping for an answer to the original question, it would tell me what I need to know.

Comment: The problem is that this is rather vague. What exactly are you trying to do here? If you explain, we may be able to help out with a idiomatic solution, not the solution that you describe (which may or may not be technically possible).

Comment: I think you should post up a actually sample/scenario as Oded said.

Comment: @Oded No offense, but I don't want an idiomatic solution. I want to know the answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, everyone. Most of the time I do need an idiomatic solution, and I provide many code examples in most of my questions, but this time I really couldn't learn any more than just a simple answer could tell me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could float the element, but that usually causes the element and its in-flow siblings to move away from where it would otherwise be were it in the normal flow. It also transforms the element into a block box. If either of these effects are undesirable, then floating is not an option.

If you want the element to remain as it is but act as if it weren't in the normal flow, then simply specifying `position: absolute` alone should suffice. If you don't specify *any* of `top`, `right`, `bottom` or `left`, then the element won't be offset anywhere from its normal flow position, except in special circumstances (e.g. absposing an element will block [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) on that element, because when it's out of flow it no longer has any other margins to interact with — compare [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/PPt44) with [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/PPt44/1)).

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I face sometimes. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @VoidKing: No problem - I expanded on it a little and included some non-essential fiddles.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what is the use case here, but here is a short explanation that i hope would clear things for you:

Every HTML has a 'Normal Flow' which is usually from left to right. Block level elements (`div`,`p`,`li`) would always take the whole line, while inline elements (`span`, `a`) would appear one next to each other.

There are several ways you can control the flow of the page:

1. Changing an element's display property (inline,inline-block,table-cell etc.)
2. Setting position absolute - that would take the element out of the 'Normal Flow' thus making room for other element to occupy that space.
3. Setting position relative - that way you can move the element from it original position, but unlike absolute positioning the element will still occupy it's original space so no other element can get in there.
4. Using floats - similar to absolute, that will take the element out of the normal page flow and will enable other elements to occupy that place.

These are the main ways, each affects the flow differently.

Hope it helped.